# Why are these columns not separating like the rows?

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

In the following, I am trying to have the column headers span the length of the matrices. The commented out `% \multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Max} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Min}` is what I wanted to use, i.e. have it say Mean, Max, and Min, for each of three columns.

That is not working, so I am trying to see why and even the following where I do `Fa` for each of the 9 columns isn't working either. The result is that the column headers are squished ont he left side.

I am also getting "Misplaced \omit" errors on Lines 96 and 99 but am unsure if that is related to this column issue.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc|ccc}
    Transformation & Fa & Fa & Fa & Fa & Fa & Fa & Fa & Fa  \\
    % \multicolumn{3}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Max} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Min} \\
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Ground Truth} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{     $\begin{pmatrix}1.197 & 0.050 & -0.026 \\ 0.178 & 1.109 & -0.23 \\ \end{pmatrix}$  
    }}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{    
     $\begin{pmatrix}1.061 & -0.324 & -1.066 \\ -0.063 & 1.026 & -1.157 \end{pmatrix}$ 
      }}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{    
     $\begin{pmatrix}1.268 & 0.362 & 0.936 \\ 0.314 & 1.262 & 0.889 \\ \end{pmatrix}$
      }}
 
    \end{tabular}
    % \caption{(Mean, STD) ... Min ... Max}
    % \label{table:transform-matrices}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a four column table. But it's too big, so some kind of adjustment is necessary.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-3pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c}
\toprule
Transformation & Mean & Max & Min \\
\midrule
Ground Truth &
$\begin{pmatrix}1.197 & 0.050 & -0.026 \\ 0.178 & 1.109 & -0.23 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ &
$\begin{pmatrix}1.061 & -0.324 & -1.066 \\ -0.063 & 1.026 & -1.157 \end{pmatrix}$ &
$\begin{pmatrix}1.268 & 0.362 & 0.936 \\ 0.314 & 1.262 & 0.889 \\ \end{pmatrix}$
\end{tabular*}

\caption{(Mean, STD) ... Min ... Max}
\label{table:transform-matrices}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you.